# Is there no video loading in github pages html?

Tags: html, github, video, html5-video

My video won't load and is hosted on github. Does github not allow videos?

I have tried many src="Links"

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="../../Websiteland/Twitter/FLT.mp4" type="video/mpeg">
Your browser does not support this awesome video title.
</video>
```

[Website for video](https://robocop79.github.io/Websiteland/Twitter/Crimeaday.html)

Comment: simply removing the type worked for me... probably not considered best practice, though.

Answer (score 5):

`video/mpeg` is a valid MIME type in the form, but it is the one of MPEG-1 videos. So browsers will try to use their `video/mpeg` decoder, won't find any or will just fail to use it on your mp4 video and finally abort.

You wanted `video/mp4`:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="https://robocop79.github.io/Websiteland//Twitter/FLT.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [seen here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1048378):

> The 'No video with supported format and MIME type found' error message is about the HTML5 media player.
>   So you do not appear to have support in Windows for playing the media file(s) in the formats that are available.
>
> See also: "[HTML5 audio and video in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=viewing-html5-audio-and-video)"

I don't see the error message in Chrome, but the video does not play either.

As an alternative, you might consider:

- uploading the video to a Video hosting service (for instance, YouTube)
- use [`nathancy/jekyll-embed-video`](https://github.com/nathancy/jekyll-embed-video) to embed the video player.

That is:

```
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ include.id }}"
      width="700"
      height="480"
      frameborder="0"
      allowfullscreen="">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks iframe is disabled by github and you cannot use this trick anymore. It says, to help protect the security information enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was case sensitivity.

The video URL isn't case sensitive when testing in chrome or VS code, but is case sensitive in your github repository and must be exact in both file name and src=""

Answer (score -2):

I have updated my GitHub page and reloaded my website (only with my website url), but it didn't work...

Then, I applied `/index.html` after my website url. It starts working (only with `website_url/index.html`).