# Can you use Lottie-Files / bodymovin on a github pages account

Tags: github-pages, lottie, bodymovin

BodyMovin / LottieFiles - requires that you have your After Effects animation in a JSON format and stored on your server.

Because GitHub Pages is a static site with no backend, does this mean that you cannot use LottieFiles with GitHub Pages?

If you can, does anyone have an example of this being done, please -

I have used bodymovin with Json After effects file to run a animation on other sites just not github pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does this mean that you cannot use LottieFiles with GitHub Pages?

Yes, the lottiefile, even declared as a webplayer in `<lottie-player>` element, would not be interpreted by GitHub.

One alternative/workaround would be to [embed a video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54396155/6309) in your GitHub page in order to show what the animation would look like.
It is possible [with Jekyll-pages](https://github.com/nathancy/jekyll-embed-video).